# How to simplify a fraction into a mixed fraction

Tags: ruby, math

I have a variable named `value`. The value is converted into a `Rational` object. I need to simplify it into a mixed fraction. I was wondering how to simplify the fraction. For example, I want to convert `513/16` to `32 1/16`.

My code looks like this:

```
value = ...
value = value.to_r #=> (1/12)
```

Comment: `value.numerator / value.denominator` would give you your desired whole number and `((value.numerator % value.denominator) / value.denominator.to_f).to_r` would give you the fraction, but I'm not sure how you would use it.

Comment: Thank you, this did it. My new script looks like this 'value = owner.width
value = value.to_r
value #=> (1/12)
whole_num = value.numerator / value.denominator
whole_num = whole_num.to_s << ' '
fraction = ((value.numerator % value.denominator) / value.denominator.to_f).to_r
fraction = fraction.to_s << '/"'
result = whole_num + fraction
result' and the results show just how I want them.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, rational is going to store itself as `numerator / denominator`.  But you could make a simplified `to_s` method to format it for you how you want.

Try this:

```
class Rational

  def to_simplified_s
    if self < 1
      to_s
    else
      truncated = self.truncate
      "#{truncated} #{self - truncated}"
    end
  end

end

puts Rational(1, 2).to_simplified_s
puts Rational(513, 16).to_simplified_s
```

Prints:

```
1/2
32 1/16
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel:

```
require 'fractional'
puts Fractional.new(513/16r).to_s(mixed_fraction: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off Nick Veys's answer, but taking care of an additional edge case when the fraction is actually a whole number:

```
class Rational

  def to_simplified_s
    if self < 1
      to_s
    else
      truncated = self.truncate
      truncated == self ? truncated.to_s : "#{truncated} #{self - truncated}"
    end
  end

end

puts Rational(4, 2).to_simplified_s #=> 2 (whereas Nick Veys's answer outputs "2 0/1")
puts Rational(1, 2).to_simplified_s #=> 1/2
puts Rational(513, 16).to_simplified_s #=> 32 1/16
```